# Restricting Certificate access from C# Code

Tags: c#, certificate, file-permissions, code-access-security

The use case:

I have a hosting platform (server) where multiple ASP.Net applications are hosted. I do not want to have application to have programmatic access to the certificates on the Server. Only the Components/libraries that are developed by the platform owners should be able to access those certificates.

Is there any way in which i can restrict application from using only platform components for doing any certificates related manupilation.

FYI all the certificates are stored as files in a fixed folder.

Can i implement some kind of Code Access permissions which can give platform libraries access to those certificate and deny other libraries/components/Application from accessing certificates?